# Как правильнее записать пустое свойство в JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Общий приветик.

В JSX есть два способа записать пустое свойство(пустую строку):

`property=""`

`property={''}`.

Какой способ правильнее и оптимальнее?

Почему он правильнее и оптимальнее?

Comment: Первый без вопросов. Он "как в html", все делают так, во всех вменяемых стайлгайдах что я видел делают так.

Comment: да хоть так! `propery={String()}` ,  `propery={``}` и т.д...
вот вы бы посмотрели как оно транспилируется в js и нам сообщили.. спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как видим из результатов транспилирования с помощью бабеля

```
<Test prop1="" prop2={''} prop3={``} />
```

превращается в

```
React.createElement(Test, { prop1: "", prop2: '', prop3: "" });
```

Вывод: разницы нет